# ZPL command based printer prints blanks in Xamarin iOS via bluetooth

Tags: xamarin.ios, zebra-printers, zpl, ios-bluetooth, bluetooth-printing

I'm trying to print something using ZPL command, but unfortunately it is getting printed as blank, I know that the printer works, because there's a sample command given with this printer and when I use this, it prints the test page.

This is the command I'm using

> ^XA^PW800^LL800^PON~SD5^FO0,0^A0N,100,100^FDHOWDY PARTNER^FS^RTPQ1^PQ1^XZ

Any inputs would be really helpful, thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed on your android device the 'Printer Setup' app from playmarket for calibrating your printer? Maybe your printing language not set to an ZPL in printer settings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).